# T-SQL Triggers performing insert causing deadlock

Tags: sql-server, triggers, deadlock

I have an SQL table called Agent_Events, which logs "jobs" for lack of a better term reported by users of our system. Jobs will start and, some indetermine time later, end. We want to keep a record of all system jobs so we have a trigger that, when a row is deleted from the Agent_Events table, gets the record, and inserted into the report_Agent_Events table a record of the job with the time the job ended, determined by the current time. This is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tAgentEvents]
ON [dbo].[Agent_Events]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON  
    DECLARE @callUID nvarchar(10)
    SELECT @callUID = [raw_call_ucid] FROM DELETED
    DECLARE @callID bigint
    SELECT TOP 1 @callID = [ID] FROM report_ExtensionCalls WHERE UCID = @callUID ORDER BY [time_finished] DESC

    INSERT INTO [report_agent_Events]
        ([Agent_Name],[time_started],[time_ended],[duration],[clientStatus],[agentStatus],[Call_ID],[Reference_ID])
        (   SELECT
                [Agent_Name],[time_started],GETDATE(),DATEDIFF(s,[time_started],GETDATE()),[clientStatus],[agentStatus],@callID as Call_ID,[Reference_ID]
                    FROM
                DELETED
        )
END
```

What we have discovered recently is that when there is a high volume of activity on the system, multiple jobs could end simultaneously. When this happens, the trigger will fail with the following deadlock error:

```
Procedure tAgentEvents:
Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim RSS
```

It looks like the INSERT statement in the trigger is conflicting with the lock imposed by the same INSERT statement in a concurrent trigger. Is there anything I can do to avoid this problem? This appears to me like a very simple trigger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your trigger needs a complete rewrite regardless of the deadlock. Your trigger assumes there will only ever be a single row deleted. Your query needs to be set based because in sql server triggers are called once per operation, not once per row.

Comment: Ah okay, I believe it was written this way because actually the rows are deleted by a stored procedure, which ensures only ever one row is deleted at once. Would that still be problematic?

Comment: Yes. What happens when there is a problem and somebody needs to delete 10 rows because of a bug in the system. Your trigger will not work correctly. It is easy to write them set based. In this case it really makes no sense to have 1 column be a scalar from deleted but the rest of them coming directly from the deleted table. This should be a simple join between your base table, deleted and report_ExtensionCalls

Comment: Ahhh I see I didn't even notice that. Was never intended to be scalar - I think the report_ExtensionCalls join was a later addition, I suspect it was just hacked in without much thought. Thanks for your help, that's already looking like it's performing better.. could this have been the cause of the deadlock or would that be unrelated?

Answer (score 1):

This should accommodate all the business rules in your original trigger but without scalar variables.

Please note, this is incredibly unlikely to solve the deadlock issue. You still need to sort that out.

```
INSERT INTO [report_agent_Events]
(
    [Agent_Name]
    , [time_started]
    , [time_ended]
    , [duration]
    , [clientStatus]
    , [agentStatus]
    , [Call_ID]
    , [Reference_ID]
)
SELECT [Agent_Name]
    , [time_started]
    , GETDATE()
    , DATEDIFF(SECOND, [time_started], GETDATE())
    , [clientStatus]
    , [agentStatus]
    , raw_call_ucid
    , [Reference_ID]
FROM DELETED d
join
(
    select top 1 ID as CallID
    from report_ExtensionCalls ec
    where ec.UCID = d.raw_call_ucid
    order by [time_finished] DESC
) e on e.CallID = d.raw_call_ucid
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the trigger to make it work in one go, with multiple lines deleted and with multiple matches in report_ExtensionCalls.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tAgentEvents]
ON [dbo].[Agent_Events]
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT d.Id AS DeletedId
            , rec.[ID]
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rec.UCID ORDER BY rec.[time_finished] DESC) AS RowN
        FROM DELETED AS d
        JOIN report_ExtensionCalls AS rec ON d.[raw_call_ucid] = rec.UCID
    )
    INSERT INTO [report_agent_Events]
        ([Agent_Name],[time_started],[time_ended],[duration],[clientStatus],[agentStatus],[Call_ID],[Reference_ID])
        (   SELECT
                d.[Agent_Name]
                ,d.[time_started]
                ,GETDATE()
                ,DATEDIFF(s,d.[time_started],GETDATE())
                ,d.[clientStatus]
                ,d.[agentStatus]
                ,a.[ID] as Call_ID
                ,d.[Reference_ID]
                    FROM DELETED AS d
                    LEFT JOIN CTE AS a ON d.Id = a.DeletedId AND a.RowN = 1
        )
END
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes that's running much better - see my comment on the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah - Just updated it to take into account if there are more the one match in report_ExtensionCalls

Comment: Should mention - there won't always be a value for [raw_call_ucid].. it will sometimes be passed as NULL. Just changin gthe first JOIN to LEFT JOIN should fix that, right?

Comment: Also there could be multiple rows in the report_ExtensionCalls table that match the UCID and I have to make sure I get the one with the greatest ID field.. will this account for that?